# Bison issue with reduce/reduce conflict

Tags: bison, yacc, reduce-reduce-conflict

So I am new to Bison and I am trying to make a simple calculator.
When I do the bison -d command it says there are 7 reduce/reduce conflicts and I am not really sure why is this, I know it's because of some bad logic in my grammar, I just can't find it. So here's the code to the .y file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Math.h>

char** nizVarijabliI;
int* nizVrijednostiVarijabliI;
int* nizIinfo;
char** nizVarijabliD;
float** nizVrijednostiVarijabliD;
int* nizDinfo;
int countD = 100;
int dountI = 100;
void updateSymbolTableI(char* s,int br);
void updateSymbolTableD(char* s,float br
float symbolVal(char* s)

%}
%union{
    double var1;
    int var2;
    char* varName;
}
%token <var1> DNUM
%token <var2> INUM
%token <varName> VARIABLE;
%token QUIT PLUS MINUS DIVIDE MULTIPLY EQUALS EXPONENTIATION SIN COS LOG POW SQRT LPAREN RPAREN NEWLINE
%right EQUALS
%left PLUS MINUS
%left DIVIDE MULTIPLY
%right EXPONENTIATION
%nonassoc UMINUS
%type <var1> mixExp
%type <var2> exp
%type <varName> assign
%start pocetak
%%
pocetak :
            |   pocetak line;

line :  NEWLINE
        |   assign  NEWLINE {;}
        |   mixExp  NEWLINE {printf("%f\n",$1);}
        |   exp     NEWLINE {printf("%d\n",$1);}
        |   QUIT        NEWLINE {exit(1);}
        ;

mixExp  :   DNUM                                                NEWLINE {$$ = $1;}
            |   SIN LPAREN mixExp RPAREN                    NEWLINE {$$ = sin($3);}
            |   COS LPAREN mixExp RPAREN                    NEWLINE {$$ = cos($3);}
            |   LOG LPAREN mixExp RPAREN                    NEWLINE {$$ = log($3);}
            |   SQRT LPAREN mixExp RPAREN                   NEWLINE {$$ = sqrt($3);}
            |   POW LPAREN mixExp "," mixExp RPAREN NEWLINE {$$ = pow($3,$5);}
            |   VARIABLE                                            NEWLINE {$$ = symbolVal($1);}
            |   MINUS mixExp    %prec   UMINUS              NEWLINE {$$ = -$2:}
            |   mixExp PLUS mixExp                              NEWLINE {$$ = $1 + $3;}
            |   mixExp MINUS mixExp                         NEWLINE {$$ = $1 - $3;}
            |   mixExp MULTIPLY mixExp                      NEWLINE {$$ = $1 * $3;}
            |   mixExp DIVIDE mixExp                            NEWLINE {$$ = $1 / $3;}
            |   LPAREN mixExp RPAREN                            NEWLINE {$$ = $2;}
            |   mixExp PLUS exp                                 NEWLINE {$$ = $1 + $3;}
            |   mixExp MINUS exp                                NEWLINE {$$ = $1 - $3;}
            |   mixExp MULTIPLY exp                         NEWLINE {$$ = $1 * $3;}
            |   mixExp DIVIDE exp                               NEWLINE {$$ = $1 / $3;}
            |   exp PLUS mixExp                                 NEWLINE {$$ = $1 + $3;}
            |   exp MINUS mixExp                                NEWLINE {$$ = $1 - $3;}
            |   exp MULTIPLY mixExp                         NEWLINE {$$ = $1 * $3;}
            |   exp DIVIDE mixExp                               NEWLINE {$$ = $1 / $3;}
            ;
exp     :   INUM                                                    NEWLINE {$$=$1;}
            |   SIN LPAREN exp RPAREN                       NEWLINE {$$=sin($3);}
            |   COS LPAREN exp RPAREN                       NEWLINE {$$=cos($3);}
            |   LOG LPAREN exp RPAREN                       NEWLINE {$$=log($3);}
            |   SQRT LPAREN exp RPAREN                      NEWLINE {$$=sqrt($3);}
            |   POW LPAREN exp "," exp RPAREN               NEWLINE {$$ = pow($3,$5);}
            |   VARIABLE                                            NEWLINE {$$ = symbolVal($1);}
            |   MINUS exp   %prec   UMINUS                  NEWLINE {$$ = -$2:}
            |   exp PLUS exp                                        NEWLINE {$$ = $1 + $3;}
            |   exp MINUS exp                                   NEWLINE {$$ = $1 - $3;}
            |   exp MULTIPLY exp                                NEWLINE {$$ = $1 * $3;}
            |   exp DIVIDE exp                                  NEWLINE {$$ = $1 / $3;}
            |   LPAREN exp RPAREN                               NEWLINE {$$ = $2;}
            ;
assign  :   VARIABLE EQUALS exp                         NEWLINE {updateSymbolTableI($1,$3);}
            |   VARIABLE EQUALS mixExp                      NEWLINE {updateSymbolTableD($1,$3);}
            ;
%%
int main() {
    int i;
    nizVrijednostiVarijabliI = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    nizVrijednostiVarijabliD = malloc(100*sizeof(float));
    nizIinfo = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    nizDinfo = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<100;i++) {nizIinfo[i] = 0; nizDinfo[i] = 0;}
    nizVarijabliI = malloc(100*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<100;i++) nizVarijabliI[i] = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    nizVarijabliD = malloc(100*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<100;i++) nizVarijabliD[i] = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    yyparse();
    return;
}
void updateSymbolTableI(char* s,int br)
{
    int freeInd = -1;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<countI;i++)
    {
        if(nizIinfo[i] == 0)
        {
            freeInd = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(freeInd == -1)
    {
        freeInd = i;
        countI = countI * 2;
        nizVrijednostiVarijabliI = realloc(nizVrijednostiVarijabliI,count*sizeof(int));
        nizIinfo = realloc(nizIinfo,count*sizeof(int));
        nizVarijabliI = realloc(nizVarijabliI,count*sizeof(char*));
    }
    nizVrijednostiVarijabliI[freeInd] = br;
    nizIinfo[freeInd] = 1;
    nizVarijabliI[freeInd] = s;
}
void updateSymbolTableD(char* s, float br)
{
    int freeInd = -1;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<countD;i++)
    {
        if(nizDinfo[i] == 0)
        {
            freeInd = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(freeInd == -1)
    {
        freeInd = i;
        countD = countD * 2;
        nizVrijednostiVarijabliD = realloc(nizVrijednostiVarijabliD,count*sizeof(float));
        nizDinfo = realloc(nizDinfo,count*sizeof(int));
        nizVarijabliD = realloc(nizVarijabliD,count*sizeof(char*));
    }
    nizVrijednostiVarijabliD[freeInd] = br;
    nizDinfo[freeInd] = 1;
    nizVarijabliD[freeInd] = s;
}
float symbolVal(char* s)
{
    int ind = -1;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<countI;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(s,nizVarijabliI[i]) == 0)
        {
            ind = i;
            return (float)nizVrijednostiVarijabliI[ind];
        }
    }
    if(ind == -1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<countD;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(s,nizVarijabliD[i]) == 0)
            {
                ind = i;
                return nizVrijednostiVarijabliD[ind];
            }
        }
    }
    if(ind == -1) return 0;
}
```

Also here's the lex file I made for this purpose:

```
%{
#include "ultcalc.tab.h";
%}
%%
"quit"                              {return QUIT;}
"sin"                               {return SIN;}
"cos"                               {return COS;}
"pow"                               {return EXPONENTIATION;}
"log"                               {return LOG;}
"sqrt"                              {return SQRT;}
[0-9]+"."[0-9]+             {yylval.var1 = atof(yytext); return DNUM;}
[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*           {yylval.varName = yytext; return VARIABLE;}
[0-9]+                          {yylval.var2 = atoi(yytext); return INUM;}
"="                             {return EQUALS;}
"+"                             {return PLUS;}
"-"                                 {return MINUS;}
"*"                             {return MULTIPLY;}
"/"                                 {return DIVIDE;}
"("                                 {return LPAREN;}
")"                                 {return RPAREN;}
","                                 {return yytext;}
[ \t]                               {;}
[\n]                                {return NEWLINE;}
.                                   {yyerror("Neocekivani karakteri!");}
%%
yywrap() {return 1;}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is a lot of code to wade through, so I didn't. However, I noticed that you are attempting to syntactically detect type (integer or double). That is not a good idea. Do your typechecking after the parse. Since you have variables and it is not possible to know the type of the variable from its name, you will end up with ambiguous parses which will be reported as r/r conflicts

Comment: Also, `yylval.varName = yytext;` is a really bad idea, and the action for `,` should be `return *yytext;` rather than `return yytext`. Personally, I'd use that action for the other single-character token types (.operators and parentheses.)

Comment: Yeah that is pretty much what I did, simplifyed the grammar and accepted all the numbers in the same way and than just did some float casting in C code. As with the `,` I replaced that with `return  yytext[0]` now.
Also could you tell me a better way to pull this off `yylval.varName = yytext;`, since it seems when I pick up VARIABLE in bison with $somenumber that it picks up more characters than it should and this could possibly be because of what you just pointed out?  @rici

Comment: So I also solved the `yylval.varName = yytext;` issue by using strcpy instead, I needed to add an additional line in lex file to allocate memory for `yylval.varName` using malloc and all seems to be fine now. Thanks for your help @rici

Comment: Copying `yytext` is a reasonable solution. Don't forget to `free()` the copy when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the primary issue of reduce/reduce conflicts by simplifying the grammar to just accept all numbers and not make the difference beetwen integers and floats when parsing, rather I just casted all numbers to float in C code later.
There were some more underlying problems mentioned by @rici in the comments, I fixed them as well and explained it in the comments area above(so I won't repeat it here).